# How to Fix 'Level must be same as name (None)' error in Pandas apply

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of 70 million rows, I am trying to add a column in the data frame by using apply function with the help of swifter library

swifter library https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter/blob/master/README.md

While I am trying to run it is giving me an error

'Level   must be same as name (None)'

```
#myfunction

def alert(c):
    if c.count(" ") == 0:
        return 'ngram1'
    elif c.count(" ") == 1:
        return 'ngram2'
    elif c.count(" ")==2:
        return 'ngram3'
    else:
        return 'NotAvailable'

all_dfs['ngram'] = all_dfs["word"].swifter.apply(alert,axis=1)


# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'word': ["abc","abd cds" ,"abc cds fgh"], 'freq': [5, 6, 7],"doc":["666","5555","333"})
```

The expected output is a column should be added with the particular value but I am getting an error 'Level   must be same as name (None)'

## Based on my thinking swifter is just able to work with numerical columns,

Any other ways would be appreciated

Comment: I tried both ways @Ben.T but the result did not changed

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the 'count' method. I tried your code with using the freq field and did not work.

This however game your expected results in the small example.

```
import string 
df['ngram'] = df["word"].apply(alert)
def alert_1(s):
    ng = sum([i.strip(string.punctuation).isalpha() for i in s.split()])
    if ng == 1:
        return 'ngram1'
    elif ng == 2:
        return 'ngram2'
    elif ng ==3:
        return 'ngram3'
    else:
        return 'NotAvailable'
    return sum([i.strip(string.punctuation).isalpha() for i in s.split()])

df.loc[:,"ngram_2"] = df["word"].swifter.apply(alert_1)
df

    word        freq    doc  ngram  ngram_2
0   abc            5    666  ngram1 ngram1
1   abd cds        6    5555 ngram2 ngram2
2   abc cds fgh    7    333  ngram3 ngram3
```

Let me know if this works for you in your larger dataset. 
Did not know about swifter, but I am going to implemented on my work from now on.

Comment: It works perfectly, I have to just iterate it quickly as possible because the data is gonna increase, And this solution is taking the almost same time. But it's great! @Jorge

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please vote for the answer, it is part of the process.

Comment: i have already voted but due to lack of my reputation it is not reflecting